# rails 4 will_paginate custom records second page not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have created a custom search of books according to the criteria the user enters and I use will_paginate to show them. However, even though the first page shows ok, when I choose the second the following error message appears:

```
Couldn't find Book with id=show_search_by_title` in show method
def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  authorize! :read, @book
end
```

In the books_controller there is the following method:

```
def show_search_by_title
  q = params[:book][:title]
  books = Book.where('title LIKE ?', "%#{q}%")
  @books = books.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
end
```

and the corresponding .erb file is the following:

```
<% if @books.empty? %>
  There are no books in the Library that fulfill the given criteria
<% else %>
  <%= will_paginate @books %>
```

The books that complete the given criteria are the following:

```
<table>    
<tr>
  <th> Book Title </th> <th> Author </th> <th> Category </th> <th> copies </th> <th> Rank </th>
</tr>

<% @books.each do |book| %>

<tr>
  <td><%=book.title %> </td>
  <td><%=book.author.name %> </td>
  <td><%=book.cat.description %></td>
  <td><%=book.copies %>  </td>
  <td><%=book.rank %> </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<%= will_paginate @books %>

<% end %>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

my routes for books are:

```
view_books_books_path            GET    /books/view_books(.:format) books#view_books
rank_book_books_path             GET    /books/rank_book(.:format) books#rank_book
update_book_rank_books_path      PATCH  /books/update_book_rank(.:format) books#update_book_rank
search_by_title_books_path       GET    /books/search_by_title(.:format) books#search_by_title
search_by_author_books_path      GET    /books/search_by_author(.:format) books#search_by_author
show_search_by_title_books_path  GET    /books/show_search_by_title(.:format) books#show_search_by_title
show_search_by_author_books_path POST   /books/show_search_by_author(.:format) books#show_search_by_author
books_path                       GET    /books(.:format)    books#index
                                 POST   /books(.:format)    books#create
new_book_path                    GET    /books/new(.:format)    books#new
edit_book_path                   GET    /books/:id/edit(.:format) books#edit
book_path                        GET    /books/:id(.:format)    books#show
```

shows the error in show method:

```
def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  authorize! :read, @book
end
```

Comment: What is the link when you hover the page 2?

Comment: Worth adding your routing for that action. Sounds like it could be a routing problem rather than a controller code problem.

Comment: the link when you hover page 2 is books/show_search_cy_title?page=2

Comment: You need to use get and not post for the form, that was the answer. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the action in the options for will_paginate https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/API-documentation#will_paginatecollection-options. What is the path of the link for the "next" button?

Comment: What is in the rails log for that request?